# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category\CategoryController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am getting really confused on how namespace and use are being used here to reference my `CategoryController`. I am using laravel 8. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

My route uses resource and that seems to be ok.
web.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category;
Route::get('/admin/categories', [CategoryController::class, 'category'])->name('categories');
```

My Category Controller is `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category\CategoryController.php` as shown here is my folder structure:

[image]

CategoryController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    public function category(){
        echo "Hello Category";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `namespaces` should mimic your directory structure. So if you have a `CategoryController.php` file that resides in the folder `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Category`, then the `namespace` for that file would be `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category;`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    // stuff
}
```

When referencing classes, you include the relevant `namespace` with the `use` statement.

So in your `web.php` file you want to replace:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category;
```

with:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category\CategoryController;
```